# Alexa Skill Messaging API vs Alert/Remainder API

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Please help me to understand the difference between Skill Messaging API vs Alert/Remainder API.  I went through the Amazon documentation. I am not able to differentiate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Skill Messaging API**

Your skill can get informed about skill events and things the user do with his shopping and todo list.
So you can subscribe to Events e.g.:

- Skill events:

  - your skill is deactivated
  - an account was linked
  - skill enabled
  - skill permission accepted
- List events: the customer created/deleted a todo list item or a item from his shopping list

**Alert/Remainder API**

You can create reminders for your customer. E.g. if there is a sports event you could notify your customer one hour upfront that the match will start.
Additionally you can also read and modify other reminders.

To confuse you completely this `Alert/Reminder API` is more close to an other Alexa feature, the  [Proactive Events](https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/smapi/proactive-events-api.html). Here you can actively send speech to the customer. E.g. you could send scored goal to your customer. [Here also a short description of it, instead of the technichal description.](https://developer.amazon.com/de/blogs/alexa/post/7822f3ee-1735-4eaa-9aa6-5b8e39953c07/proactiveeventsapi-launch-announcement)
The Proactive Event API is sending notifications (yellow light on devices without screens)

Comment: Alert -  "barges in" the message but Proactive Events don't do. Please correct me if I am wrong.   Proactie Event user need to check if they have any notifications

Comment: You are right. Alert just happen without user interaction but Proactive Events are so called notifications e.g. with yellow ring and you have to ask for it.